# How many committees can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

A company has 7 designers, 14 manufacturers, 4 testers, 5 in sales, and two in accounting. A committee of 6 people is to be formed.

How many different committees can be formed if there must be exactly 2 from manufacturing?

I know that first step should be to choose the 2 from manufacturing. So that would be 14 choose 2.

What should I do from here? I'm fairly new to Combinatorics and I haven't quite got the thinking of it yet.

Comment: How would this change if the question read "at LEAST 2 from manufacturing?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to choose two from manufacturing $\binom{14}{2}$ and then 4 from the remaing 18 people that is $\binom{18}{4}$, thus

$$N=\binom{14}{2}\binom{18}{4}=\frac{14!}{2!12!}\frac{18!}{4!14!}=278'460$$

committee of 6 people can be formed.

Answer (score 1):

There are $18$ people left to choose from, and we need to fill an additional four seats in the committee. That's $\binom{18}{4}$. Now multiply the two and you have your answer.

If we change to *at least* two from accounting, then we can do it like this: (each one is calculated exactly the same way as the first part)

- How many ways if there are exactly two from accounting?
- How many ways if there are exactly three from accounting?
- How many ways if there are exactly four from accounting?
- How many ways if there are exactly five from accounting?
- How many ways if there are exactly six from accounting?

and then add them. If that seems a bit long, then there is a simpler way: Instead count the number of committees that do *not* fulfill the criteria, count the total number of committees without any criteria and subtract one from the other.

Committees that do not fulfill the criteria are committees where either

- None come from manufacturing
- Exactly one come from manufacturing

and again, you calculate each of these exactly as you did the first part.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to calculate this. What I mean is that if the numbers had been larger so that whichever of the two approaches here you chose you would get a large number of cases, then you really do have to calculate a large number of cases.